# создать struct Student

Tags: c++

Есть структура

```
struct Student
{
char *name;
char *surname;
char *group;
char **exams;   
};
```

у меня есть метод который создает Student

```
void CreateStudents(Student *&student)
{
    if (!student)
    {
    student = new Student{};

    cout << "Enter name student: ";
    student->name = new char[20]{ '\0' };
    cin.getline(student->name, 20);

    cout << "Enter surname student: ";
    student->surname = new char[20]{ '\0' };
    cin.getline(student->surname, 20);

    cout << "Enter surname student: ";
    student->group = new char[10]{ '\0' };
    cin.getline(student->group, 20);

    CreateExams();
    }
}
```

а внем вызываеться еще 1  метод который должен заполнить exams, вот в нем ошибка, invalid null pointer, помогите разобраться. А задача функции, для каждого студента создавать 3 экзамена. Вижу я это так, может скажете, что не правильно думаю: Указатель на -> указатель из 3 элементов -> exam1, exam2, exam3.

```
 void CreateExams()
    {
        Student *student;
        const short examsLenght = 3;
        student->exams = new char *[examsLenght] {nullptr};
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        {
            cout << "Enter " << i + 1 << "exam: ";
            cin.getline(*(student->exams + i), 10);
        }
    }
```

Comment: а вам принципиально не можно использовать `stl`?

Comment: Нет, это указатель на первый элемент массива из 3 указателей, которые никуда не указывают.

Comment: Сомневаюсь, что это последняя ошибка. Странно как вообще не было ошибки о том, что в `CreateExams` указатель не инициализирован это раз. Вы заполняете экзаменами новый указатель, который не умеет отношения к тому, что создавался ранее. А последнее, вы используете арифметику указателей `cin.getline(*(student->exams + i), 10);` при это у вас `exams` это `char(1 byte)`, а вы хотите сместиться на `int(4 byte)`. В этом месте буде ошибка чтения из памяти.

Comment: raviga спасибо, я вас понял на счет смещения, попробую реализовать подругому, а stl использовать нельзя